# convert 'pdf master' into a normal pdf

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a document/printing issue, made more difficult because I don't know the correct terminology to use... however, here goes!

I have inherited a pdf document that I needed to edit. OK, fine. However, the document is a version designed for going to printers - it has colour gamut info at the top, and border markings around the edges showing where the paper should be cut etc.

For my output, I just need a 'normal' PC version. Ideally, I want to keep the content of the PDF, and have it fill the page, without all this 'printer/publishing info'.

What's the normal way to handle that? Is there some option in Adobe that I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use specific graphics software. Better asked on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (But the answer is: there is no "printer's stuff" in a PDF -- something is "in" the PDF or it is not. Use the Crop function of Acrobat Pro to remove the border outside of the crop marks.)

Answer (score 0):

in the end, I used the option to print to PDF, and in the print screen, choosing 'actual size' would hide the borders and save as a clean final version.

Works OK :)